Blazor Server AuthenticationStateProvider
I have Blazor server app, (built using the .NET7 Blazor server template, upgraded to .NET8 in place). I want to trigger my code on AuthenticationStateChanged.
In program.cs, I have this line (which I think came from the original template):
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();

In my MainLayout.razor, I want to run code on login state changed. I have the following code:
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider authProvider
private async void AuthStateChanged(Task<AuthenticationState> authStateTask)
{
    var authState = await authStateTask;

    if (authState != null)
    {
        if (authState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            licenseService.LoadLicense(); //call the license service to set license.
        }


    }
}

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    authProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged += AuthStateChanged;
    AppState.MenuChanged += ChangeState; //event fired in AppState
    settings = await DataService.GetSettings();
    AppState.ClinicName = settings?.ClinicName??"KFA Dental";

}

and from the template:
public class RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<TUser>
    : RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider where TUser : class
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;
    private readonly IdentityOptions _options;

    public RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider(
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
        : base(loggerFactory)
    {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
        _options = optionsAccessor.Value;
    }

    protected override TimeSpan RevalidationInterval => TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

    protected override async Task<bool> ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync(
        AuthenticationState authenticationState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Get the user manager from a new scope to ensure it fetches fresh data
        var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
        try
        {
            var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<TUser>>();
            return await ValidateSecurityStampAsync(userManager, authenticationState.User);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (scope is IAsyncDisposable asyncDisposable)
            {
                await asyncDisposable.DisposeAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                scope.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task<bool> ValidateSecurityStampAsync(UserManager<TUser> userManager, ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(principal);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (!userManager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            var principalStamp = principal.FindFirstValue(_options.ClaimsIdentity.SecurityStampClaimType);
            var userStamp = await userManager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user);
            return principalStamp == userStamp;
        }
    }

    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
        var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user));
    }

    public void AuthenticateUser(string userIdentifier)
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
        [
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userIdentifier),
    ], "Custom Authentication");

        var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(
            Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user)));
    }
}

The problem is that AuthStateChanged() is not firing. Do I need to make any changes in the RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider()?

Is there a check on the order of service registration, such as calling services.AddRazorPages() and services.AddServerSideBlazor() before calling builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>()?
